# Checking a user's Zip Code against a short list of qualifying Zip Codes

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am setting up a website for a service that will have a limited delivery area and we want a way for a user to type their zip code in to see if we deliver to their area. We only have 16 - 18 zip codes that we will deliver to, so not a huge list - it probably would not even require a database. Looking for a quick solution so HTML5? Javascript?

Honestly have not tried anything yet, but had no idea where to start, as I am more of a designer than a developer. Thanks for any help or ideas you all have!

Answer (score 0):

Although your question won't be well recieved (because of no effort), this is pretty straight forward. The [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method can search for simple strings in an array. It returns `true` if found or `false` otherwise. So you can do this:

```js
const zips = ['12345', '67890'];
console.log(zips.includes('12345'));
```